# Wordpress weird issue link transform to base64

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, image, base64

I have an issue with a piece of code.

```
if (jQuery("article img").length) {
  console.log(jQuery("article img"));
  jQuery("article img").wrap("<a id='single_image' href="+jQuery("article img")[0]["src"]+" alt='image article'></a>");
  jQuery("a#single_image").fancybox({
      fitToView: false,
      maxWidth: "80%"
  });
}
```

Well, i have an image on my page and i would like, when i click on this image, that a window appears and zoom this image to be more readable so i'm using fancybox.

Sometimes there is an issue. When i open console and search `jQuery("article img")[0]` i have this code :

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3161" src="http://foyerdecluny.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2015_Remise-diplomes-AFPA.jpg" alt="2015_Remise-diplomes-AFPA" width="2048" height="1183" srcset="http://foyerdecluny.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2015_Remise-diplomes-AFPA.jpg 2048w, http://foyerdecluny.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2015_Remise-diplomes-AFPA-300x173.jpg 300w, http://foyerdecluny.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2015_Remise-diplomes-AFPA-1024x592.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 2048px) 100vw, 2048px">
```

So as you can see the src is totally normal.
But here is the magic. If i make a `console.log(jQuery("article img")[0]["src"])` the value is : `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==` and no more a link with http...

So I don't really understand what is happening here...

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the fault of the plugin Rocket Lazy Load. I delete it and now it's working.